# Compiler aborts tests

Tags: function, variables, haskell, testing, compiler-errors

I have tried to specify variables in functions, but it didn't help.

functions:

```
prop_unzip_check :: forall a b. Ord a => [(a,b)] -> Bool
prop_unzip_check xs = length (unzip (xs::[(a,b)])) >= 0

prop_merge_check :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
prop_merge_check xs ys = length (merge (xs::[a]) (ys::[a]))
                           == length (sort ((xs::[a]) ++ (ys::[a])))
```

And after compiling I receive this confusing error:

```
> Test property "prop_merge_check" ... aborted.
Reason: Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `quickCheckBool'
prevents the constraint `(Arbitrary a0)' from being solved.
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
These potential instances exist:
  instance Arbitrary QCGen -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary'
  instance Arbitrary (a b c) => Arbitrary (WrappedArrow a b c)
    -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary'
  instance Arbitrary (m a) => Arbitrary (WrappedMonad m a)
    -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary'
  ...plus 80 others
  (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `prop_merge_check'
prevents the constraint `(Ord a0)' from being solved.
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
These potential instances exist:
  instance Ord (Encoding' a)
    -- Defined in `Data.Aeson.Encoding.Internal'
  instance Ord DotNetTime -- Defined in `Data.Aeson.Types.Internal'
  instance Ord JSONPathElement
    -- Defined in `Data.Aeson.Types.Internal'
  ...plus 310 others
  (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but testing `length _ >= 0` is pointless.

Comment: yeah, i understand, that`s just a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by defining certain functions as Int instead of any type of functions 'a'.

```
> prop_unzip_check :: [(Int,Int)] -> Bool
> prop_unzip_check xs = length (unzip (xs::[(Int,Int)])) >= 0
```